# Regular Expression To Match a Word That Contains Certain Letters

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to write some code that pulls a list of words from a text file and then provide it with a bunch of letters and then match words that contain all those letters. So, if I enter the letters "lheol" it would match "hello".

The regex I was thinking off is something like:

```
string =~ /(?=.*l{2})(?=.*h{1})(?=.*o{1})(?=.*e{1}).*/i
```

However that would match say "Hellod" when I just want it to match the word "hello".

Any ideas?

Comment: `/\b(?=.*l{2})(?=.*h{1})(?=.*o{1})(?=.*e{1}).*\b/i`?

Answer (score 3):

Solving this problem with regular expressions is not a good fit due to the fact that there could be a large number of combinations of the letters in a word.  Consider instead sorting the letters of the search word and each target and checking string equality.

```ruby
class String
  def sort
    self.chars.sort.join.downcase
  end
end
'hello'.sort # => 'ehllo'
'leloh'.sort # => 'ehllo'
'Hellod'.sort # => 'dehllo'
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression isn't really needed. If you just want to find out if a word contains at least one instance of each letter, you can check for character inclusion.

```
def word_match(word, letters)
  letters.split(//).uniq.each { |char| return false unless word.include? char }
  true
end
```

The nice thing about doing it this way is that you fail fast anytime a letter isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show you how it *can* be done using regex (which also means that the burden of trying all the possible combinations, if needed, lies on the regex engine):

```
if subject =~ /^(?:h()|e()|l()|l()|o()){5}\1\2\3\4\5$/
    # Successful match
else
    # Match attempt failed
end
```

The trick is that each letter is followed by an empty capturing group `()` which always matches. Then, at the end of the regex, the backreferences `\1\2\3\4\5` make sure that every letter has participated in the match exactly once (because the previous alternation allows exactly 5 repetitions, and all five capturing groups are checked.

Comment: @pguardiario: Yeah, don't try this at home, kids :)